# Converting Python 2.7x to 3.x compatability issues: Issues with format and subprocess.Popen, numpy.array, and floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.8

I am continuing my sojourn into transitioning about 15 (multiple authors/sources) years of Python scripts into Python 3 and have run into an issue that I *assume* is Python 2.x versus Python 3.x, but could be mistaken on. Code below.

In 2.7x the code below works just fine (minus the `universal_newlines` flag added). Here `output` is a tuple, with `output[0]` a (perhaps long) string of floats and integers (example output below code). In 3.x/8 the cpu format goes a wee-bit haywire and comes out uncallable. What is interesting is that `step` *seems* to be just fine.

I am thinking there might be something different in how floats are handled, but in reading up on it, nothing becomes readily apparent. So, suggestions are welcome.

```
 cmd = """grep CPU %s | gawk '{print $8, $11}' """ % (logfile)
 p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,    universal_newlines=True)
 output = p.communicate()
 lines = output[0]
 cpu = numpy.array(map(float, lines.split()[0::2]))
 step = numpy.array(lines.split()[1::2], dtype=int)
```

Python 2.7x:

```
output[0]

<type 'tuple'>
<type 'str'>
36.3838 745701
29.4391 745702
23.4954 745703
22.6346 745704
```

Python 3.8x:

```
output [0]

<class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
42.3777 139371
41.811 139372
44.1033 139373
43.0248 139374
```

Comment: `map` doesn't return a list in python 3.x, maybe this could be an issue? But what's the expected output for 3.x? and how is it changed?

Comment: Okay,

I will answer my own question because I just found out the issue.

cpu = numpy.array(map(float, lines.split()[0::2])) as mentioned does not return a list

so,

cpu = numpy.array(list(map(float, lines.split()[0::2])))


seems to work, which is just an annoying change.

Comment: What was wrong with just running [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) on your code? It should have already fixed this issue.

Comment: I looked at 2to3, and sometimes it worked, other times it made a bit of a mess of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the answer

cpu = numpy.array(map(float, lines.split()[0::2]))

needs to be changed to

cpu = numpy.array(list(map(float, lines.split()[0::2])))